# Uncheck last checkbox in td to enable other checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How to make this work? When Bar is unchecked, others input checkbox remove disabled in each td? I am a beginner in Jquery :)

The original code is taken from
    [Original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240672/jquery-check-and-disable-checkbox-on-checking-another-checkbox)

```
<table border="1" id="re">
    <tr>
<td class="class1"><input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="ss"/>ss</td>
<td class="class1"><input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="aa"/>aa</td>
<td class="class1"><input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="dd"/>dd</td><td class="class1"><input type=checkbox checked="checked" value="bar"/>Bar</td></tr>

    <tr>
<td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="ss"/>ss</td><td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="aa"/>aa</td><td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="dd"/>dd</td><td class="class1">
         <input type=checkbox checked="checked" value="bar"/>Bar
        </td></tr>
     <tr>
<td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="ss"/>ss</td><td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="aa"/>aa</td><td class="class1">
    <input type=checkbox  disabled="disabled" value="dd"/>dd</td><td class="class1">
         <input type=checkbox checked="checked" value="bar"/>Bar
        </td></tr>
    </table>

$('.class1 input:last-of-type').live('change', function () {

var n = $(this).siblings('input:checkbox');
if (!$(this).attr('checked')) {
    n.attr('disabled',false);

} else {

    n.attr('disabled', true); 
} 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[value="bar"]', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var checked = $this.is(':checked');
    var others = $this.closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('disabled', checked)
    if(checked){
        others.prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ba7xD/)

Comment: Hello, May I know if I checked value bar, can it uncheck other?